# WordPress menu has been assigned but not showing

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm quite new to the whole WordPress thing but I'm experienced with HTML/CSS anyway. I've created a new Menu within the Admin area of WordPress but when assigned to the theme, it still doesn't show correctly. Apologies in advance if I'm being totally blind here but PHP isn't my strong point too.

So below is the code in question, related to where the menu is in the header section:

```
<div id="nav-primary" class="nav"><nav>
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logged-in-menu' ) ); /* if the visitor is logged in, this primary navigation will be displayed */
    } else {
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); /* if the visitor is NOT logged in, this primary navigation will be displayed. if a single menu should be displayed for both conditions, set the same menues to be displayed under both conditions through the Wordpress backend */
    } ?>
</nav></div><!--#nav-primary-->
```

I know that the 'header-menu' is pointing to a new Menu I set up, but it's not showing the correct one. Instead, it's showing lots of menu items, when the one I set up has only 4 items.

Can anyone shed any light on this at all? I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Check this step.

1. Have you added this function in function.php file. If no add this.

   /* Add two custom menu */

   ```
               function register_my_menus() {
                 register_nav_menus(
                   array(
                     'logged-in-menu' => __( 'Logged in Menu' ),
                     'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' )
                   )
                 );
               }
               add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
   ```
2. Have you selected menu from Appearance > Menu for both of your menu ? If no then create menu and select that.

Let me know still you need any help.

**EDIT**
New code for logged in and not logged in use  menu.

```
/* Add two custom menu */ 
function register_my_menus() { 
    register_nav_menus( 
        array( 'top-menu' => _( 'Top Menu' ), 
            'header-top-menu' => _( 'Header Top Menu' ) ) ); 
    } 
    add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' ); 


    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
        { wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top-menu' ) ); } 
        else { wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-top-menu' ) ); } 
        ?>
```

Comment: I just realized that I didn't have the Logged In menu selected under Appearance > Menu. That's showing ok now but I do have a small menu above the main menu.

Is there a way of having 2 menus in the Header area?

Comment: Yes you can add as much you want, just create one more menu in function and add it to hear file.

Comment: Ok, so additional menu would be like this in functions.php?

/* Add two custom menu */ function register_my_menus() { register_nav_menus( array( 'logged-in-top-menu' => _( 'Logged in Top Menu' ), 'header-top-menu' => _( 'Header Top Menu' ) ) ); } add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

I'll add the above code to functions.php and then add the below where I'd like the additional menu to appear?

<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logged-in-top-menu' ) );
} else {
 wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-top-menu' ) );
} ?>

Comment: @MarkO'Donoghue Please  correct the answer if you find this answer proper.

Comment: Ok I put in that code and made sure it's doubled checked and etc... But it's still not picking up the 'Main Top' menu (Which is the smaller custom menu above the Main one)...

Comment: @MarkO'Donoghue I think you did not add that menu in function file, or not set it from backend

Comment: I changed the words 'Logged in Top Menu' in functions.php to say 'Main Top' as that's what it's called under Appearance > Menus in WordPress. But that still doesn't pick it up at all, even though it's been created.

Comment: @MarkO'Donoghue Please use the edited code. I think I have cleared all.

Comment: It worked! Finally! Thanks for the help! Now I just need to work out how to style that menu.